# how to make connection between 2 separate transactions in golang

Tags: database, go, transactions

In golang i am creating 2 separate transactions. As a part of the first transaction I am creating new records in tables (let's say A). After committing the first transaction, I am starting the second transaction through which I am updating the table B record with the table A id. Now since both are separate transactions, How to handle a case where the second transaction fails and the first transaction got successful? We want the if the second transaction fails then whatever records we are creating in the first transaction got deleted.

```
main function {
err = function1() // handles 1st transaction
err = function2() // handles 2nd transaction
}
```

`A (ID,UUID,NAME) B(ID,UUID,NAME,A.ID)`

Also, the reason for creating 2 separate transactions here is we need to update the Table A id in table B records and that would be only generated after committing the first transaction,

I am thinking of adding defer function in the main function which checks whether there is an error or not. if there is error then delete records which were created as a part of 1st transaction

Comment: The solution depends on the underlying database system and whether or not it supports transactions for this scenario. For most cases, you should create one transaction, perform both actions, and then commit.

Comment: as Burak Serdar say, do it in  database system but golang

Comment: yes, agree on creating only one transaction to wrap the operation of those 2 tables, and also maybe you can check out the CTE if the query is getting more complex

Comment: Yes its supports transaction but i cant do it in one transaction since in 2nd operation i need to update db table B with id of table A which i will get only after commiting 1st transaction

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to commit the first transaction to get the id from table A.

In the example below, it uses Postgres SQL with tables A and B.

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id INT,

  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id)
);
```

The golang code can get the id of insert id of the first insert entry into the table without committing the transaction is below. It is important to note that if there is an error in the second insert the whole transaction is rolled back, therefore the data is not inserted into A.

```golang
func insert(db *sqlx.DB) error {
    // Start the transaction.
    tx, err := db.Beginx()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var aId int
    // The returned id is stored in the variable "aId".
    if err := tx.Get(&aId, "INSERT INTO a DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id"); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    var bId int
    // Use the insert id from table A.
    if err := tx.Get(&bId, "INSERT INTO b (a_id) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id", aId); err != nil {
        // In case of an error, rollback the transaction, this is the case where the A entry
        // is automatically removed as well.
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    // Else commit the transaction.
    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

meybe you can write a rollback func to remove data in function1 if there is an error in function2:

```golang
func insert() {
    err := function1() // handles 1st transaction
    if err == nil {
        err = function2() // handles 2nd transaction
        if err==nil{
            rollback1()
        }
    }
}
```